# Questions about User Authorization in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a simple user authorization system where a .txt file stores the username and password information.  I know this probably should be done differently (via databases), but I'm doing this for practice. If anyone could help me with my questions, it would be greatly appreciated.

So far I have the register.php and login.php built, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  Here are my three questions:

1. Let's say I have an html site that I want protected.  How would I incorporate the login.php so if a user who is not logged in tries to access the content of the pages, they are prompted to log in?  Would I have to put something in the  of each html page?
2. How would I implement cookies in this process?  A user who logged in shouldn't have to re-login for 20 minutes.   Ideally, I would want to send the cookies after the user has logged in, but how would I do this?
3. I want my register.php to check for existing users so all names are unique.  What I have so far does not do this correctly.  What is wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php

$check = 0;
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$name = strtolower($name);
$password = htmlentities($_POST['apw']);
$filename = getcwd() . "/psverification.txt";
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
printf ("Hi %s,</br />", $name);
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
    list($username, $pw) = explode('|', $line);
    if($username == $name && $pw == $password)
$check++;
break;  
}
if ($check == 1){
//Redirect to home page
Header("Location: index.html");
}
else{
printf("Your username or password are invalid. Please try again.");

}

}

?>

<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>
Username:<br />
<input type = "text" id="name" name="name" size="20" maxlength="40" />
</p>

 <p>
 E-mail Address:<br />
 <input type = "text" id="apw" name="apw" size="20" maxlength="40" />
 </p>

 <input type="submit" id="submit" name ="submit" name ="submit" value="Log in" />

 <p>
 <a href="register.php">Register</a></p>
 </form>
```

REGISTER.PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpw = $_POST['confirmpw'];
$username = strtolower($username);


//Check if passwords match
if ($password != $confirmpw){
print "Passwords do not match, please try again.";
}
else{
//the data
$data = "$username|$password\n";

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("psverification.txt", "a+");

 // Cycle through the array
while (($buffer = fgets($fh, 4096)) !== false)
{
    // Parse the line
    list($usercheck, $passwordcheck) = explode('|', $buffer);
    if (trim($usercheck) == $username)
 {
 print "The username is already in our system.  Please use another one.";}

else {
fwrite($fh, $data);
//Redirect to home page
Header("Location: index.html");
}

 }
 //close the file

fclose($fh);


}
}

?>

<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <p>
  Username:<br />
 <input type = "text" id="user" name="user" size="20" maxlength="40" />
 </p>

  <p>
  Password:<br />
  <input type = "password" id="password" name="password" size="20" maxlength="40" />
  </p>

 Confirm Password:<br />
 <input type = "password" id="confirmpw" name="confirmpw" size="20" maxlength="40" />
 </p>

 <input type="submit" id="submit" name ="submit" name ="submit" value="Register" />
 </form>
```

Thanks in advance.  Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably break this up into separate questions. At least the #3 part as it isn't conceptual, but your actual code.

Comment: Agreed. Separate, more specific questions would be more appropriate.

Comment: @all I appreciate your answers. I wish I could mark everyone's answer as "accepted"...they all help me a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

You would probably make use of [php's include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). All pages would make use of this. If user is not logged in then redirect them to a login page. This is good practice in general. This file may also include universal functions or other user information.

Question 2:

You don't have to use cookies. Instead I would think about [using sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php). Here you would store whether or not they are logged in server side.

Question 3:

Ask this in a separate SO question. You need to define what 'does not work' means. Have you tried debugging it at all? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Would it be possible to show me an example of how to use php's include?

Comment: It is very easy. Create a file called global.php in the root of your website. Then add `include '/global.php';` to the top of any of your pages. The code in that page will execute just as if it were actually in every page.

Comment: So in my particular case, I should include '/login.php'; in the top of all my content pages?  Would this mean the user would have to log in on every page?

Comment: No, global would contain code checkingn whether the user is authorized to access the page. If not they get redirected.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your 3rd part:

As per the code you have written, it'll just check the provided username with the first username in the list. If these do not match, write to file and redirect. You see, you are not checking against the entire list of usernames.

Try this:

```
$match_found = false;

while (($buffer = fgets($fh, 4096)) !== false)
{
    // Parse the line
    list($usercheck, $passwordcheck) = explode('|', $buffer);
    if (trim($usercheck) == $username)
    {
        print "The username is already in our system.  Please use another one.";
        $match_found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$match_found)
{
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    //Redirect to home page
    Header("Location: index.html");
}
```

Comment: This works great. THANKS!  If you would like, I can ask another question and will mark this as the accepted answer (since others have recommend this be a question by itself).  Just give me the word.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If your problem is already solved, I don't think there is a need to create a separate question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your first question, I would perhaps consider using PHP's [sessions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to ensure that only authenticated users are allowed to see the page. You could have a model where a login page is used to login initially (or have a form on any page for this that sends the data to the PHP login page), and all of the pages that a user needs to be logged in to see could first check to see if they have a valid session. If there is not a valid current session, a redirect header could be used to send the login page instead.
A simple implementation might look like this on any given page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== 1) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Would it be possible to include some form of cookies so users from the same computer who have already logged in, don't have to?